# storing data in express,node, react and react native ( cookies,sessions,localstorage,asyncstorage )

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

The problem is that in node express server side i set a cookie to store some data ,in react i can view the data from the cookie set by server but in react-native i can't use cookie ,not a good solution. What would you recommend me to store the data in from server side so i can also use in react-native and react(both) ?

```
//inside server.js
//set cookie works with react but not react-native
   let options = {
       maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 15 * 4 * 24 * 365 * 10, 
       httpOnly: false,
       signed: false 
   }

   thecookiedata = "Cookie Data here";
   res.cookie('coockiename',thecookiedata, options);
//set cookie works with react but not react-native
```

Alternative to this  so it works for both react and react-native ?

Comment: in react native you can use the keychain to securely store stuff

Comment: yeah but must work for both express/react and react-native ,must be compatible

Comment: Can't you take the cookie, store it on the keychain and then use it in subsequent requests?

Comment: not allowed do to fact that data will persist ,it's a token that has the user credentials so he does not log out of the app and web ...

Comment: Exactly, so store that token on the keychain. Then pull it out of keychain when you go to get data from the server

Comment: nope keychain not a good solution , must be universal to work both in react and in react-native ,keychain is for react-native only

Comment: it must work for both web app ( react ) and mobile app ( react-native) ,the keychain method is good only for mobile app ,it must be  something that i set in express / react and then i can see it in react-native ,similar to a cookie or a session...

Comment: .... They are different platforms. The way you securely store is going to be different based on platform. I'd use cookies on the browser as that is one of the best ways to do that. But on mobile implement a different storage method using keychain